# TypeError: Illegal invocationType when passing file through ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My goal is to pass a file to my backend which runs on laravel. The file is **drag and dropped** on the web page and not my `input file`. I went through the previous issues on stack overflow and fixed my code accordingly but still the issue exists.

Here is my javascript code that uses ajax to pass the file

```
$("html").on("drop", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    var dt = e.dataTransfer || (e.originalEvent && e.originalEvent.dataTransfer);
    var files = e.target.files || (dt && dt.files);

    if (files) {
        for (var i = 0; i < e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files.length; i++) {
            var file_ext = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files[i].name.split('.').pop();
            console.log(file_ext);

            if ((file_ext == 'pdf') || (file_ext == 'docx') || (file_ext == 'txt')) {
                console.log('right file');

                var resume = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files[i].value;
                var form_data = new FormData();
                form_data.append("resume", resume);
                var resume_val = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files[i].name;
                console.log(form_data);

                var token = $('#token').val()
                var hello = "hello";

                $.ajax({
                    url: '/resume_upload',
                    type: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                    },
                    data: ({
                        resume: form_data,
                        wish: "Naveen its working"
                    }),
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data.msg);
                        alert(data.msg);
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                        console.log(error);
                        alert(error)
                    }
                });
            } else {
                console.log('wrong file');
            }
        }
    } else {
        console.log('file not recieved');
    }
});
```

Here is where i get the file

```
var resume = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files[i].value;
var form_data = new FormData();
form_data.append("resume",resume);
```

But when i `console.log(form_data)` it logged **FormData{}** just empty form data. So obviously i pass nothing with my ajax function. Am i doing anything wrong in getting the file ? I don't have an idea how to go about this.

Comment: try without the `.value`

Comment: you should pass the entire file so remove the `.value`

Comment: Still have the same issue , Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation in jquery .min.js file and in my html file at the line where my ajax function begins. HTMLHtmlElement.<anonymous> at $.ajax({ @dandavis @.value

Comment: where does `event` come from? as in `event.preventDefault();` also, i think security measuers audit which function is accessing the `dataTransfer` object; you might not be able to sub-class it with a jQuery delegated event compositor...

Comment: @dandavis edited the question. It was e.preventDefault(); still have the same issue. and i get only empty in DataForm{}

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I misunderstood what do you want but I think you should do stg like this:

```
var form_data = new FormData();
form_data.append('resume_file_name', e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files[i].value);
form_data.append('resume_file', e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files[i]);
form_data.append('wish', "Naveen its working");
```

if u want to upload the file, not just some file info

and with `FormData`, you can pass all the data you want, so just pass this to `$.ajax` data parameter:

```
data: form_data,
```

and there is something else, may this was the original problem:
when `jQuery` handles the parameters it also tries to convert it, but this causes problems, when pass a `FormData` type to data attribute, so you should also add these parameters to the `$.ajax` input object:

```
processData: false,
contentType: false
```

parameters.

Sorry for my bad english!

Comment: As you can see the problem is the file is not getting appended to the FormData

Comment: Because you tried to append its name and value, but not the file (as @dandavis and Beginner tried to say too). When you post a file, you also posts the main parameters, like name, mime type, last modified datetime

Comment: i did pass it like this var resume = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files[i]; but still the same

Comment: Here is what I did:

I created an empty html with your code, and my modifications, and it worked. You are right: the FormData will be empty, but it sends the data, when you dumps the $_FILE on the server (if you use php). You need my test files?

Comment: yes i would like to test your files. can you send it to nknaveen328@gmail.com ?